# Integrating during a least squares approximation, are these partial integrals correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

I would like to find the least squares approximation:

$$g(\alpha_0,\alpha_1) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} [\sin x-\alpha_0-\alpha_1x]^2dx$$

Taking the derivatives w.r.t. the alphas I end up with: $$2\int_0^{\pi/2} [\sin x-\alpha_0-\alpha_1x](-1)dx=0$$ when the derivative is taken w.r.t $\alpha_0$ and:

$$2\int_0^{\pi/2} [\sin x-\alpha_0-\alpha_1x](-x)dx=0$$ when $\frac{d}{d\alpha_1}$ is taken.

Solving, I come up with: $$-1+\frac{\alpha_0(\pi/2)}{2}+\frac{\alpha_1(\pi/2)}{3}$$ and $$-2+2\alpha_0(\pi/2)+\frac{\alpha_1\pi}{4}$$ as my system of equations. Are these correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:

$$ 2\int_0^{\pi/2} -\sin x + a_0 +a_1 x\ dx = 2\cos x \mid_0^{\pi/2} + 2a_0x\mid_0^{\pi/2} + a_1x^2\mid_0^{\pi/2}.$$

This yields a linear equation for $a_0$ and $a_1$, i.e. $ca_0 + da_1 = k_1$.

You will find a similar equation from you second integral, and get another linear equation for $a_0$ and $a_1$. Then, you'll have a linear system of two equations and two unknowns, which should be easily solved.

Comment: That was what I was forgetting, thank you. I will report back with results.

Comment: I've edited the question with my results. Would you mind taking a peek and seeing if they look correct?

Comment: Hopefully it does because I went ahead and solved the system anyway! Thank you for your help.